# Magento 1.9 addAttributeToFilter not working

Tags: magento-1.9, product, product-attribute, sql

I need to get all products that have set the SpecialToDate attribute.

I have a code but is not displaying any product.

```
 $_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
 $_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')

               ->addFinalPrice()
               ->getSelect()
               ->where('price_index.final_price < price_index.price')
               ->addAttributeToFilter('SpecialToDate', 1);
```

I also tried to add a condition inside the foreach but is displaying only 2 products from 5. The 2 products are id 1 and 2, the other 3 products have ID 6001 and 6002, so like is not retrieve all special products.

```
 <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $product): 

        if($product->getSpecialToDate() != null) {

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The attribute code is not valid as it is case sensitive in the method parameter.

You need to replace your code with:

```
addAttributeToFilter('special_to_date', $validDate);
```

Where `$validDate` must be a valid date

Comment: Can you explain how the $validDate should be? I tried with this $validDate = Mage::getModel('core/date')->date('Y-m-d');

Comment: @GeorgeGeorge try the date as `Y-m-d H:i:s`